# Как реализовать функцию React.createElement без использования React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

моя задача - написать 2 функции:

React.render

React.createElement

Я застрял с React.createElement.

```
    const React = {
        createElement(element, props, ...children) {
            let elem = document.createElement(element);
            console.log(elem)
            console.log(children)

            return elem
        },

        render(app, root) {
            root.innerHTML = app
        }
    }
```

Это включает в себя рекурсию, но я не могу понять, как это работает и как построить эту функцию.

```
 var reactElementUl = React.createElement(
        'div',
  { style: { backgroundColor: 'red' } },
  [
    React.createElement('span', undefined, 'Hello world'),
    React.createElement('br'),
    'This is just a text node',
    React.createElement('div', { textContent: 'Text content' }),
  ],
    );

    React.render(reactElementUl, document.getElementById('app'));
```

в конце должно получиться текст с красним фоном
        Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: поинтересуюсь: зачем вам это? Что вы хотите получить?

Comment: `root.innerHTML = app` скажите привет xss инъекциям))))

Comment: Вы не знаете, как делается рекурсия?

Comment: в таком случае нет